# How to read GPS coordinates on iPhone or Nokia e73 through java application (phone connected to laptop with cable)?

Tags: java, iphone, gps, coordinates, nokia

Can I read the iPhone's file system from java application? 
My iPhone 3G is connected to laptop by cable and I want that my java code knows in every moment whats the GPS location of iPhone.

That data must be stored in some "string" on iPhone don't you think?

EDIT: Since with iPhone this is imposible, how about with **Nokia e73**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

1. Create a simple web application based on Java tech stack
2. Add Geolocation API detector to your web app that submits the user's location to server
3. Use the service on your phone

Tada?

Comment: f*****g apple and their closed policies. I'll better try it with different phone. tnx

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no file accessible via USB that provides the current GPS coordinates. You'd have to write a custom app to run on the iPhone that would turn on Location Services and continuously write the position to a file.

Comment: Even with a custom App accessing that data is not as simple as plugging a cable in... some kind of network connection would definitely help.

Comment: I wrote a little utility app for the iPhone that streams NMEA, GPX & KML data to a URL - it could easily be your own wifi network.
It's at www.capsicumdreams.com/iphone/gps2ip/
It won't solve the OP problem, but it's a solution for Eiko's comment